# How to solve for a variable when this variable is inside a summation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a complex equation, and I'm trying to move $w_j$ to the right side of the equation.

$$Expression= w_j$$

Below is the equation I'm having trouble with:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{h_j}{1+e^{-\sum_{k\ne j}^nw_kh_k-w_jh_j}}=0$$

Where,

$h_j$, $w_j$: an array of positive real numbers, for example, [0, 6, 3, 1,7, 3]. Hence $h_0=0$, $h_1=6$, $h_2=3$, $h_3=1$, $h_4=7$, $h_5=3$.

The best I could come up is moving the $w_j$ to another euler constant

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{h_j(x_i)}{1+\frac{e^{-\sum_{k\ne j}^nw_kh_k(x_i)}}{e^{w_jh_j(x_i)}}}=0$$

Can anyone give me a hint on how I can move the $w_j$ to the right side of the equation?

Comment: What do you meant by *split*?

Comment: Oops, I meant to move the $w_j$ to the right side of the equation.

Comment: Sorry, does variable not mean things like $w_j$ and $w_j$?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me at all, so I can't tell you anything certain. Maybe someone else will be able to help

Comment: @You'reInMyEye Sorry for the bad wording. I've updated my question, does this makes more sense?

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted the exponent in the denominator there. I think  that it is the sum $-\sum_k w_kh_k(x_i)$, sum over all $k$, and they’ve split out the one term indexed by $k=j$.

Comment: @Lubin Ohh, I did the split out one term, it was originally, $1+e^{-\sum_{j=0}^nw_jh_j(x_i)}$

Comment: Now I have a serious question: is $h$ a linear function, perhaps? Maybe I'd also like to know: what are the $x_i$’s ?

Comment: $h_i$ can do nothing and equal to $x_i$, ie. $h_i(x_i) = x_i$, however, $h$ is not a linear function. You can think $x_i$ are random points on a 1 dimensional line from [0, Inf], such as [0, 0.1, 53, 13, 33]. The number of $w$ should be equal to $h$. Essentially the Summation of $w_i h_i(x_i)$ can be converted to matrix equations $w^th$, which will equal to a number when computed.

Comment: You probably mean "Expression" instead of "Equation", as an equation features an equal sign.

Comment: @AlexProvost Thanks, I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks extremely difficult. You have $n+1$ variables, $w_0,\dots,w_n$, and you want to solve this equation for one chosen $w_j$ in terms of the others. From a formal or theoretical standpoint, it looks like it could be done. But the problem is that your variable $w_j$ appears in the denominator (not to mention as part of the argument of an exponential function) in every one of the summed terms (one for each $i$). If you have values for the $x_0,\dots,x_n$ and for the other $w_?$’s, you might be able to solve numerically for $w_j$, but I think that even that might be hard. I suggest setting $n=1$, so that you have two $x$’s and two $w$’s, and seeing whether you can solve for (say) $w_0$ in terms of $w_1$. Things may simplify surprisingly, but I doubt that very much.

Comment: Yeah... I've been trying to solve this equation for days. Thanks for your input, I can try to solve for N=1.